# When creating a react project in Visual Studio Code for the first time, after entering npx create-expo-app command, got this message on the terminal

Tags: javascript, react-native, visual-studio-code

```
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\THARA\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\THARA\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

how to fix this?

I was trying to create a react project in Visual Studio code.

Comment: Please mention the steps to reproduce the error, and please add more details and highlight the exact problem

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not cd into a directory where you want to create your React native projects or you didn't specify the folder name.

You can solve this by doing

```
mkdir react-native-project 
npx create-expo-app react-native-project
```